# How can I create a Installer package for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I create a Installer package for iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expose your question in a detailed and better way. Are you using xcode? It has everything you need to build your app for the iPhone.

You just code the app, and hit the button "build" or "build and run" and the .app file is automatically generated.

Comment: I just want to make bundle of audio files that each have six audio file. and Its download my app from iPhone. Is it possible?

Comment: Include those audio files as resources in your Xcode project.  They will be copied to the device as part of your .app bundle.  You can then get to them via the [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath].

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "installer package" for iPhone.  As a developer, you create an app bundle, containing the executable and all resources, and just zip that and upload it to the App Store via iTunes Connect.

Detailed instructions for uploading an app to the App Store are available in the iPhone program portal.

Installation of an app on the device is handled by the iPhone OS and the App Store or iTunes (or by Xcode during development).